# Как исправить не корректное отображение тега  в IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Здравствуйте, кто уже сталкивался с ситуацией, что в чудо браузере IE - отображение такого фрагмента кода

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Название</legend>
    Тело
</fieldset>
```

как в CSS `border: 1px solid #000;`
Другими словами IE игнорирует тег legend, хотя смотрел на сайтах он его поддерживает. 
Есть ли какие-та способы заставить ИЕ в моей проблеме работать корректно.
 P.S Моя версия браузера IE 10.
Спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доктайп Html5 и

```
<script>
document.createElement('fieldset');
document.createElement('legend');
</script>
```

Не?